# What is the proper relationship between these models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I need some help thinking through the appropriate relationship between my models in a Rails application.

In my application, I would like Users to be able to follow what other Users post, based on topics. So for example, User A may want to follow User B, but only when User B writes about Topics X and Y (not Topic Z). Topics will be like tags in the application, where a user can tag a post with one or more topics.

Here's what this might look like:

User A follows User B on Topics X and Y

User B follows User A on Topics G and H

User C follows User A on Topic D

User C follows user B on Topics P and Q

I know I need models for User, Topic and Post, and likely some sort of join models. But I'm not sure the structure of the join tables and the appropriate Active Record relationships to use here.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following, with a join table called users_topics

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_topics, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_user_topics, class_name: User, through: :users_topics
end

class UsersTopic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :followed_user, class_name: User, foreign_key: :followed_user_id
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_topics, foreign_key: :followed_user_id
  has_many :following_users, :class_name User, through: :users_topics

  # there doesn't seem to be a reason to declare the other user association, 
  # which is also achieved through users_topics
end
```

So, if we have:

```
     model     id
     User A    1
     User B    2
     Topic X   1
     Topic Y   2
```

Then the users_topics table will contain:

```
     id        user_id     followed_user_id topic_id
     1            1            2               1
     2            1            2               2
```

So User A has a UsersTopic instance for User B and Topic X, and also has a UsersTopic instance for User B and Topic Y.

and so on, for each of the other scenarios you describe